# add character at column N in file

Tags: bash, awk, emacs, sed

I have a code file for which no line exceeds `N`. (let's say `N=80`) Here is an example:

```
class A
{
    int a;
};
```

I want to insert spaces for every line until the character count of the line reaches `N`, then insert a custom character `c`, which could be anything. So for our example:

```
class A                                                                        c
{                                                                              c
    int a;                                                                     c
};                                                                             c
```

Besides writing a small program to do that, how can you archieve this in `emacs` and/or bash?

Comment: Add up spaces where? put up an example.

Comment: `printf '%80s\n' "c"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understood the question: suppose you have the following file, file.txt

```
name
10
100 20
more text here
```

By using the following:

```
awk '{printf("%-80sc\n",$0)}' file.txt
```

You would get:

```
name                                                                            c
10                                                                              c
100 20                                                                          c
more text here                                                                  c
```

Edit: If the sample code you provided is indented with spaces, the above `awk` will also work.

Comment: Excellent. With `awk` you could get fancier and select specific sections of the file to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want output that looks like those `c`s are all in the same location, you're going to want to convert all tabs to the corresponding number of blank chars using, for example, `pr -e -t` before padding. Look what happens without and then with the `pr` when your input contains tabs:

```
$ printf 'class A\n{\n\tint a;\n};\n'
class A
{
        int a;
};

$ printf 'class A\n{\n\tint a;\n};\n' | awk '{printf "%-20sc\n", $0}'
class A             c
{                   c
        int a;             c
};                  c

$ printf 'class A\n{\n\tint a;\n};\n' | pr -e -t | awk '{printf "%-20sc\n", $0}'
class A             c
{                   c
        int a;      c
};                  c
```